# Undefined javascript variable in for loop

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, undefined

I have a json file returning me something like :

```
{"id0":"58955","id1":"15614","id2":"897987"}
```

I parse that json, and call the values with for instance identifier.id1

I want to display all my identifiers in a for loop, I tried this but it comes "undefined undefined undefined". If I replace manually identifier.idk with identifier.id1 in my loop, it works and shows 15614.
Where is my mistake ?

here is my code

```
identifier = JSON.parse(output)

var html = '<table border="0">';
html += '<tr valign="top" ><td><b>Identifiers :</b></td>';


for (var k = 0; k < 3; k++) 
    {
        html += '<tr>';
        html += identifier.idk;
        html += '</tr>';
};

html += '</tr></table>';
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it is looking for idk in your object! JavaScript does not magically know that you want the string "id" and the integer k to be concatenated together. You need to tell it to do that.

Use bracket notation.

```
identifier["id" + k];
```

And now for your next problem, you have no tds! I think you want td instead of tr in your loop.

Comment: This should work perfect for you iLearnToDev ....!!!

Comment: Thank you very much, that's a newbie mistake, I didn't realize!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `identifier.idk` use `identifier["id"+k]`.

Explanation:

`identifier.idk` looks for a property called literally `idk` inside your identifier object; the `[]` form of property reference lets you construct a string and use that as a property name.

As a general comment it might be nicer to have an array in there rather than doing string manipulation to create property names on the fly.